# Failure to instantiate KeyAgreement under IBM AIX 6.1

Tags: java, bouncycastle, javax.crypto, secure-random

We need to deploy a standalone jar in an IBM AIX 6.1. This jar tries to connect to an SFTP server using hierynomus sshj and bouncycastle. When trying to instantiate the KeyAgreement, in execution time, it outputs the following:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:222)
        at java.lang.Class.forNameImpl(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:172)
        at java.security.Provider$Service$1.run(Provider.java:831)
        at java.security.Provider$Service$1.run(Provider.java:823)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:202)
        at java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Provider.java:821)
        at java.security.SecureRandom.<init>(SecureRandom.java:114)
        at javax.crypto.b.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)
        at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:200)
        at javax.crypto.KeyAgreement.getInstance(Unknown Source)
        at net.schmizz.sshj.common.SecurityUtils.registerSecurityProvider(SecurityUtils.java:88)
        at net.schmizz.sshj.common.SecurityUtils.register(SecurityUtils.java:267)
        at net.schmizz.sshj.common.SecurityUtils.isBouncyCastleRegistered(SecurityUtils.java:245)
        at net.schmizz.sshj.DefaultConfig.<init>(DefaultConfig.java:78)
        at net.schmizz.sshj.SSHClient.<init>(SSHClient.java:135)
        at com.dxc.seat.eai.EailSftpClient.getConnection(EailSftpClient.java:312)
        at com.dxc.seat.eai.EailSftpClient.startProcess(EailSftpClient.java:200)
        at com.dxc.seat.eai.SFTPFileInput.main(SFTPFileInput.java:17)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.drbg.DRBG$NonceAndIV.engineGenerateSeed(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureRandom.generateSeed(SecureRandom.java:343)
        at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.drbg.DRBG$HybridSecureRandom.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.drbg.DRBG.createBaseRandom(Unknown Source)
        at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.drbg.DRBG.access$200(Unknown Source)
        at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.drbg.DRBG$Default.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)
        at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:200)
        ... 19 more
```

The JVM used to run this jar is:

```
java version "1.6.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build pap6460sr9fp1ifix-20110511(SR9 P1+IZ97552))
IBM J9 VM (build 2.4, JRE 1.6.0 IBM J9 2.4 AIX ppc64-64 jvmap6460sr9-20110203_74623 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
J9VM - 20110203_074623
JIT  - r9_20101028_17488ifx3
GC   - 20101027_AA)
JCL  - 20110203_01
```

The JVM security settings have been updated by appending the new security provider to the end of the list of providers at java.security and by adding the libraries:
bcpkix-jdk15on-1.60.jar
bcprov-jdk15on-1.60.jar to the ext directory.

The standalone jar has been built using maven-assembly-plugin.

We wonder why this is happening and how we could fix it.